# Numba jit unknown error during python function

Tags: numpy, numba

I made this function, but numba always give me error. Both chr_pos and pos are 1D arrays. What can be the problem?

```
@nb.njit
def create_needed_pos(chr_pos, pos):
    needed_pos=[]
    needed_pos=np.array(needed_pos,dtype=np.float64)
    for i in range(len(chr_pos)):
        for k in range(len(pos)):
            if chr_pos[i] == pos[k]:
                if i==1 and k==1:
                    needed_pos=pos[k]
                else:
                    a=pos[k]
                    needed_pos=np.append(needed_pos,[a])
    return needed_pos

needed_pos=create_needed_pos(chr_pos, pos)
```

The errors:

```
warnings.warn(errors.NumbaDeprecationWarning(msg,
<input>:1: NumbaWarning: 
Compilation is falling back to object mode WITHOUT looplifting enabled because Function "create_needed_pos" failed type inference due to: Cannot unify array(float64, 1d, C) and int32 for 'needed_pos.1', defined at <input> (5)
File "<input>", line 5:
<source missing, REPL/exec in use?>
During: typing of intrinsic-call at <input> (9)
File "<input>", line 9:
<source missing, REPL/exec in use?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message

```
Cannot unify array(float64, 1d, C) and int32 for 'needed_pos.1'
```

is telling you that you are trying to assign an integer variable to an array. That happens in this line:

```
        needed_pos=pos[k]
```

You can do that in normal Python, but Numba requires static types. You must assign an array of floats to an array of floats. For example, replacing the line by

```
        needed_pos = pos[k:k+1]
```

The same error message says you are trying to assign an int, and this indicates that `pos` receives an array of ints. You must pass an array of floats instead.

After those changes, Numba still complains here:

```
needed_pos = []
needed_pos = np.array(needed_pos, dtype=np.float64)
```

with the message

```
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Cannot infer the type of variable 'needed_pos', have imprecise type: list(undefined)<iv=None>.
```

because it doesn't know the type of the elements that `needed_pos` will contain.

You can replace those two lines with one that creates an array of size zero with a known type:

```
needed_pos = np.array((0,), dtype=np.float64)
```

Now the program compiles and produces the same result with or without Numba.

But a problem remains. Numpy arrays work best when they have a fixed size. If you are continuously adding elements you'd better use lists (Numba lists in this case). This way for example:

```
@nb.njit
def create_needed_pos(chr_pos, pos):
    needed_pos = nb.typed.List.empty_list(nb.float64)
    for i in range(len(chr_pos)):
        for k in range(len(pos)):
            if chr_pos[i] == pos[k]:
                if i == k == 1:
                    needed_pos = nb.typed.List([pos[k]])
                else:
                    needed_pos.append(pos[k])
    return needed_pos
```

Comment: thank you for your fast answer. I tried to run your function, but get this error:
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 420, in _compile_for_args
    error_rewrite(e, 'typing')
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Cannot unify ListType[float64] and ListType[int32] for 'needed_pos.4', defined at <input> (10)

"

Comment: My example follows the types in your original example. But `Cannot unify ListType[float64] and ListType[int32]` implies you are passing an array of int32 in argument pos.
If you need to pass int32 values, you must declare `needed_pos` as `nb.typed.List.empty_list(nb.int32)`.

Comment: thank you, it's working perfectly! Thanks for help!

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if you're happy with it. Thanks.